# Sorting List by hierarchy

Tags: c#, list, sorting

i need to sort a list by a hierarchy, can someone give me a hand? The list looks like this:

```
        // create your list
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        // populate it
        persons.Add(new Person("child", "father"));
        persons.Add(new Person("father", "grandfather"));
        persons.Add(new Person("grandfather", "grandgrandfather"));
        persons.Add(new Person("grandgrandfather", null));
```

I want something like:

- grandgrandfather
- grandfather
- father
- child

I've tryed to implement IComparable in my classe "Person", like this:

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public String ID { get; set; }
    public String ParentID { get; set; }

    public Person(String id, String pid)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.ParentID = pid;
    }

    public Int32 CompareTo(Person right)
    {


        if (this.ID.Equals(right.ID))
            return 0;

        if (this.ParentID == null) return -1;
        if (right.ParentID == null) return 1;


        return this.ParentID.CompareTo(right.ID);
    }
```

}

but it isn't doing the thing...

Comment: You're not going to be able to implement an IComparable, because you have to know ever other item in your collection to compare them.  Any chance you have an int generation property on your person class that says they're the first, second or third generation?

Comment: You need a topological sort, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788364/building-ordering-a-tree-as-a-list-in-c-sharp/7789273#7789273. We need more details about your actual problem to be able to help more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compute the dept of items in the hierarchy, and sort the list by dept:

If the following is the person class:

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public string Parent {get; private set;}

    public Person(string name, string parent) 
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

This is an example of a method that computes the dept of a person in the hierarchy.

```
int GetDept(List<Person> list, Person person) 
{
    if (person.Parent == null) return 0;
    return GetDept(list, list.First(p => p.Name == person.Parent)) + 1;
}
```

Then the method can be used to sort the list by dept

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

// populate it
persons.Add(new Person("child", "father"));
persons.Add(new Person("father", "grandfather"));
persons.Add(new Person("grandfather", "grandgrandfather"));
persons.Add(new Person("grandgrandfather", null));

var sorted = persons.OrderBy(p => GetDept(persons, p));

foreach(var person in sorded)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", person.Name, person.Parent, GetDept(persons, p))
```

This will print:

```
grandgrandfather null                0
grandfather      grandgrandfather    1
father           grandfather         2
child            father              3
```

Note that in this example the dept is not computed efficiently as the `GetDept` method will get itself called again and again and also it uses O(n) lookup over a list. All these can be improved by computing the dept only once for each person and storing it, combined with a more efficient look up mechanism like a dictionary in order to get good performance for large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't have a way to determine which is greater if the values are spread too far apart.  For example: Your grandfather and child elements will always return -1 since the string "father" is always less than the string "grandfather".  Try making your person values into constant int values and then comparing like this:

```
const int child = 0;
const int father = 1;
const int grandfather = 2;
const int greatgrandfather = 3;

// create your list
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

// populate it
persons.Add(new Person(child));
persons.Add(new Person(father));
persons.Add(new Person(grandfather));
persons.Add(new Person(grandgrandfather));

public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Person(int id)
    {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public Int32 CompareTo(Person right)
    {
        if (this.ID == right.ID)
            return 0;

        if (this.ID > right.ID) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the logic of your `public int CompareTo(Person right)` method according to your sorting logic.

For example

```
if (this.ID == grandgrandfather &&  
        right.ID == grandfather) return 1;


if (this.ID == grandgrandfather &&  
        right.ID == child) return 1;

....... a lot more
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a data problem. You are trying to compare string values, but there is nothing inherent in your data that provides relative relationships.

I would suggest that you convert your values to an Enum, which could then be easily compared. Here is some pseudo-code that I have not tested, but which should give you an idea:

```
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
        public enum Types: int {
            None,
            Child,
            Father,
            Grandfather,
            GrandGrandFather
        }
    public Types ID { get; set; }
    public Types ParentID { get; set; }

    public Person(Types id, Types pid)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.ParentID = pid;
    }

    public Int32 CompareTo(Person right)
    {
        return this.ParentID.CompareTo(right.ID);
    }

}
```